# How to kill a daemon process in linux?

Tags: services, kill

I have a small client-server code. In the server part, there was a command `daemon(1,1)` that ran it as a daemon. The executable was just `a.out`. How can I kill this process?

The usual `ps` does not show this process, but I know this is running because I cannot use the IP-port pair anymore.

Comment: Have you tried `top`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. 
To see the processes, I used:

```
ps -ef | grep a.out
```

This gave me the list of all processes `a.out`. After this I used `kill -9 pid` to kill those processes.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in many ways. You can check the process using

```
top
```

command or you can use

```
ps aux | grep a.out
```

This command will show you all the process running (even the zombie processes)

You can use `kill -9 pid` which will kill the process signal. But a better way is to use

```
kill -11 pid
```

The above approach will create core dump files which are helpful for troubleshooting at later stage.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `killall executable-name`. It kills all instances of the given program and you don't have to check it's PID to kill it.

Comment: That was the exact solution for my case. Thanks.